# What is the default "org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount" used when it is not specified any?

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I have some scheduled tasks in a Spring application and they were configured like this:

```
<bean id="scheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <!-- Here the list of tasks -->             
        </list>
    </property>     
</bean>
```

I'm having some issues (some tasks doesn't run when they should but not always just after a long time or at certain times) and I think it may be because there are many tasks (11 so far) and the system can't run them at the same time. I have thought of setting `org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount` like this to increment the number of parallel threads:

```
<bean id="scheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <!-- Here the list of tasks -->             
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="quartzProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount">15</prop>
        </props>
    </property>     
</bean>
```

But I wonder, how many threads was the system using when I was not setting the `org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount` property? What is the default behaviour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When googling "SchedulerFactoryBean.java" first link([SchedulerFactoryBean.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SchedulerFactoryBean.java.html)) with source code i opened had:

```
public static final int DEFAULT_THREAD_COUNT = 10;
```

This value is used later to set *org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount* in *initSchedulerFactory* method:

```
mergedProps.setProperty(PROP_THREAD_COUNT, Integer.toString(DEFAULT_THREAD_COUNT));
```